# Identify genes from sCNA and point mutations

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genome

I need to find the genes that overlap deletions and point mutations that I found in my analysis.
I have a file with a list of repair genes, I have 3 files:

- A list of repair genes `RepairGenes.bed`
- A list of deletions `Deletions.tsv`
- A list of point mutations `PointMutation.pm`

*RepairGnes.bed*

```
start   end         Name
133589333   133763062   ABL1
105235686   105262088   AKT1
40736224    40791443    AKT2
109525996   109531436   ALKBH2
```

*Deletions.tsv*

```
start   end
1823208 1831709
3631182 3661599
127006  135852
2089816 2097867
```

*PointMuation.pm*

```
position
396264 
774520 
774692 
1574863
```

I need to find the list of all genes that overlap (think like an intersection between two sets) `RepairGenes.bed`, `Deletions.tsv` and *PointMutation.pm*.
I've tried a bunch of package from Biocondictor like  IRanges and GenesOverlap but they seems to do something else.
Does anyone know how can I deal with this task?

Comment: Can you add example of wanted output and files using `dput` function.

Comment: The output should be the rows of RepairGenes.bed that have an overlap in Deletion.tsv

Comment: So what's about PointMutation? Please read and edit your question according to: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also, there's no chromosome information.

Comment: Thank you, Maybe I'm not that clear in the question, I'm going got edit it. The point mutations file is needed because, after filtering RepairGenes.bed looking at the overlapping deletion I have to filter again RepairGenes.bed keeping only rows where the position in point mutation intersect RepairGenes.bed.

Comment: `GenomicRanges::findOverlaps` or `data.table::foverlaps` should work for this. What have you tried and failed, please share the code.